# What is the purpose of this 5 V protection circuit?

Tags: protection, esd

I'm working in the OEM company and I want to know what the purpose of the below circuit is.

Whether +VCC5V0 or -VCC5V0, Q8 is off so I don't know the purpose of this circuit. It should be a protection circuit, I think.

Can anyone explain this curcuit?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that power is provided from the left (at VCC5V0) and taken from the right (at VCC5V0_ESD) I suppose the purpose of the circuit is to discharge C628 (and possibly more capacitors connected between VCC5V0_ESD and GND) and thus turn off the circuit to the right quickly as soon as power is removed.

I.e. Q8 will turn on only for a short moment after power is removed.

Without transistors Q7A, Q7B, Q8 (e.g. just with diode D29 and capacitor C628) after removing power at VCC_5V0 voltage at VCC5V0_ESD might drop too slow leaving the circuit too long in an undefined/bad mode of operation.

Comment: Hi Curd,
Thank you for reply. I understand now!

Answer (score 0):

Starting at the right of R534, there are two paths to the node connecting the Q7A and Q7B bases.  One is through Q7a, b-e junction, and the other is through D29 and Q7B's b-e junction.  Because o the extra D29 Vf, the second path requires a larger voltage to begin conduction, so Q7B remains off in normal operation.

When external power goes away, C628 now is powering the circuit.  There is only one circuit path, through Q7B and R535; D29 blocks the path through Q7A.  This turns on Q7B, which turns on Q8, which discharges C628.

Comment: Hi AnalogKid,

Thank you for help reply. I understand now!